# How to handle unexpected error connection in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have chat project using WCF duplex with net.tcp binding. I've build in IIS 7.5

But I have issue related to callback which is implemented in client side. When client hit disconnect button, it works well, but in case, client crashed for some resaons as disconnecting network, computer shutdown, etc. After that, service doesn't work correctly. It seems service get error too.

My Chat Service Interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="ServiceChat", SessionMode=SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract=typeof(IChatCallback))]
public interface IChat
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Connect(Client client);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
    void Disconnect();

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
    void Refresh();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void Whisper(string target, string content);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
    Room[] GetRooms();

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
    bool CreateRoom(string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false)]
    bool JoinRoom(string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void LeaveRoom(string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void SayToRoom(string roomName, string content);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void InviteMember(Client client, string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void KickMember(Client member, string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void DisconnectRoom(string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void DisconnectAllRoom();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, IsInitiating = false)]
    void SendFile(string target, File file);
}
```

My Service Callback:

```
public interface IChatCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay=true)]
    void RefreshClient(List<Client> clients);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveWhisper(Message message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveRoomMessage(string roomName, Message message);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientConnect(Client joinedClient);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientDisconnect(Client leaver);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientJoinRoom(Client joinedClient, string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientLeaveRoom(Client leaver, string roomName, bool kicked);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveNotifyClientDisconnectRoom(Client owner, string roomName);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceiveInvitedMessage(Room room);

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void ReceivedFile(File file);
}
```

How to handle this unexpected error ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx) on duplex services. As warned by microsoft:

> The duplex model does not automatically detect when a service or client closes its channel. **So if a service unexpectedly terminates, by default the service will not be notified, or if a client unexpectedly terminates, the service will not be notified.** Clients and services can implement their own protocol to notify each other if they so choose.

So you'll need to implement a check whenever you try to send data back to the client. Never make the assumption the connection is still pure with every transmission, as it could have already failed without the service knowing it yet.